# Plan a schedule in optaplanner that takes breaks into account

Tags: optaplanner

In short: 
I have made a timetable that needs to be populated with lessons. I use **timegrains** so lessons can be all from 5 minutes to 120 minutes. My problem is that sometimes a long lesson has 1 or more breaks of x minutes inside of it.

In example: Let say that the schedule has timeslots of 45 minutes followed by a 15 min break.

```
Monday:
09:00 -> 09:45 (timeslot1)
09:45 -> 10:00 (break1)
10:00 -> 10:45 (timeslot2)
10:45 -> 11:00 (break2)
11:00 -> 11:45 (timeslot3)
11:45 -> 12:00 (break3)
12:00 -> 12:45 (timeslot4)
12:45 -> 13:00 (break4)

Same schedule applies for the rest of the week...
```

How can I schedule for 1 lesson of **90min** (2 x 45min) and to be sure that it comes after each other (lets say timeslot1 and timeslot2)?

I know I can make 2 lessons of 45 minutes, but then I need logic to handle that the lessons should be held after each other. And the code will get even "uglier" if I have a schedule with different length of timeslots and breaks.

Comment: FWIW, see also the OptaPlanner docs chapter "Design Patterns" which have design patterns to deal with time.

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I have done that and that is why I use the timegrains pattern. But perhaps that was a bad idea? Do you have any other good suggestions?

Comment: In conference scheduling we might have had similar constraints, but I think we pinned the 2 sequential lessons - there was just one instance. That just uses the Timeslot pattern (not timegrain, even though talks have different lengths).

Answer (score 0):

I solve this **Double-Lesson** issue by having two separate Lessons each with a length of 45 minutes and by adding a constraint that rewards them if they are held directly following each other. In the constraints stream-API this looks as follows:

```
factory.from(Lesson.class)
        .join(Lesson.class, equal(Lesson::getCourse, Lesson::getCourse),
            equal(Lesson::getDay, Lesson::getDay))
        .filter((first, second) -> (second.getTimeslot() - first.getTimeslot() == 1)
            && lessonNeedsToBeDoubleLesson(first))
        .reward("reward Double lessons", HardSoftScore.ofHard(1));
```

The function `lessonNeedsToBeDoubleLesson()` checks if a Lesson needs to be planned as **Double-Lesson**.

Comment: As mention this is something I can do, but then I need to know up front when I want to have a break inside the lesson. Let say that not all lessons are 45 minutes. And sometimes a lesson kan be broken up to 30min + 60min, or 15min + 75min or perhaps in this case 45min+45min. I want a more flexible solution and only define the lesson length.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constraint checking for the overall length of all lessons of that type to be 90 minutes.
You could then add lets say up to 3 Lessons of that type and allow the lesson Length to be 0.
Optaplanner will then either put one Lesson in a 90 minutes slot and make the other lessons zero lenght or it will put all 3 Lessons in Slots with lets say 20, 20 and 30 Minutes. 
Then you have to add a constraint checking for all 3 Lessons following each other as described in my other answer.

Comment: How can I implement this functionality? I thought the lesson had to be predefined to a fixed length.

Comment: If I understand your setup correctly you only need one planning variable which is the starting timeslot. The length of a lesson could be calculated from the timeslot.

Comment: Yes I have a startinTimeGrain per lecture which is a planningVaiable and also a durationInTimeGrains that tells how long a lecture is should be.

Answer (score 0):

An idea to try out:

- use **timeslot** pattern.
- interface Lesson (not a planning entity)
- @PlanningEntity ActiveLesson extends Lesson.

  - genuine planning entity
  - has genuine shadow vars room and timeslot
  - has a FollowingLesson
- FollowingLesson extends Lesson

  - shadow planning entity
  - it's room and timeslot are shadow variables that source on the ActiveLesson's room (same one) and timeslot (one later, null if day between or last).

Comment: Are there any similar example I can have a look at? I feel that I only have scratch the surface of Optaplanner and I have not really gotten the hang of shadow variables yet.

Comment: Is it possible to use timeslot pattern? Depending on the subject some lessons are 30 minutes, other 45 and sometimes only 10 minutes (or something else). Is it a good choice to use timeslots instead of timegrain? My though is that it is impossible to make this work with timeslots

Comment: I basically when for the timegrain pattern, but with a durationTimeGrain that varies in length. If a breaks comes between a lesson the endingTime increase with the same amount that the break is. It works great :) I tried using a shadow variable to update the new endingtime, but then the initial solution from optaplanner was not good at all.